# Mailman mail list nntp support

Tags: email, mailing-list, nntp, mailman, usenet

Using mailing list provide by mailman was a little bit ... user unfriendly so I try to find how can I get some nntp endpoint from a mailman mailing list in two different cases :

- Case #1 : I got access to the mailman server configuration and can install some package to get a NNTP endpoint.
- Case #2 : I don't have any access to the mailman configuration nor server. But I can install / deploy on an other server packages / script to provide some kind of "sync" with a nntp endpoint.

I make some research on Google and it seems there's dozen of script / package that post to a mailman mailing list from nntp but don't find and mailman to nntp solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Mailman 2.0 has support for [bi-directional NNTP gateway](http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/mailman-admin/node27.html).

Check **Mail-to-News and News-to-Mail gateway services** option in [administration WEB interface](https://oit-nb.rutgers.edu/documentation/mailman-mailing-lists/mail-news-gateways).

[image: NNTP Host and Linked Newsgroup Options]

[image: Gateway to News and Gateway to Mail Options]

Answer (score 1):

One software package that provides an NNTP interface to mailing lists is http://trainedmonkey.com/projects/colobus/ which integrates with ezmlm rather than mailman, but I imagine conversion between storage formats should not be too difficult and there may be migration scripts already available. Colobus is used on `nntp.perl.org` for the Perl community mailing lists.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, or alternate, try `gmane.io`:

> In January 2020, the server hosting the e-mail to news service, still
>   operated by Ingebrigtsen, needed to be moved following the sale of a
>   company Ingebrigtsen had co-founded.[8] Due to failure of the current
>   owners of gmane.org to update a DNS entry — resulting in the
>   unavailability of news.gmane.org — Ingebrigtsen obtained a replacement
>   domain, gmane.io, and migrated the 15,000 mailing lists to a new
>   server at the new address using a combination of automation, volunteer
>   labor, and manual processes.[9] It is currently available only by
>   newsreader as the website formerly operated by Yomura has not been
>   recreated.

The `NNTP` server would be `news.gmane.io` and there's a `gmane.discuss` newsgroup.  I didn't know about mailman `NNTP` until now, but `gmane` goes back some time.

(The new domain and lack of a website might've been accidentally on-purpose, as some folks would from time to time make threats -- but that's speculation.)